# Move a list inside the parent tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, list, move, prepend

I have a list in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtkLgh5z/2/) which is drawn as,

```
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
<li>List 3</li>
```

How can I add its parent tag, ie, move that list to an ordered list tag using jquery so that it becomes,

```
<ol>
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
<li>List 3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `wrapAll` method:

```
$('li').wrapAll('<ol></ol>');
```

Or in vanilla JavaScript:

```
var ol = document.createElement('ol'),
    lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

lis.item(0).parentNode.appendChild(ol);

[].forEach.call(lis, function(e) {
   ol.appendChild(e);
});
```

Note that you shouldn't use JavaScript for fixing markup! Fix whatever generates the markup. If it's a html document, open it in your favorite text editor, and fix the markup like a gentleman.

Comment: Thank you. The list is generated dynamically from a server side code. That's why I wanted to add the parent tag after rendering the list.